# How do I add items of multiple arrays with respect to their indexes in dart?

Tags: arrays, list, dart, indexing, addition

CODE:

```
  void func({String value}) async {
   
      final QuerySnapshot snapshot = await _firestore
          .collection('users')
          .where("id", isEqualTo: signedInUser.id)
          .get();

      snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
        List<dynamic> arr = element.data()["array"];

        print(arr);

        }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
I/flutter (27759): [10, 20, 30, 33, 34, 24]
I/flutter (27759): [2, 42, 45, 23, 85, 51]
I/flutter (27759): [32, 53, 12, 67, 34, 23]
```

This is what I get when I print the list from Firebase document.

**How do I add items of the arrays for each respective indexes? Like; 10 + 2 + 32 for index 0**

Comment: I couldn't understand your question? Could you provide an example of what do you want to result to be?

Comment: I've updated the question. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the `List` of `List`s and then using a for loop sum the data like:

```
var lists = snapshot.docs.map((e) => e.data()['array']);
var sums = <int>[];
for (int i = 0; i < lists.first.length; i++) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var list in lists) {
     sum += list[i];
  }
  sums.add(sum);
}
```

Be aware that this code is not tested, and you need to make sure that the lists are of equal length or the code might not work as you expect/throw an exception.